# Catching error but there is no error

Tags: java, exception

When debugging this code, the object is created with parameters. But after running the line that sets parameters, the code jumps to the `return` statement inside the `catch` block, but there are no errors in variable `e` (exception).

```
public cartao parseJSON(String jsonParam) {

    cartao jsonCartao = new cartao();

    try {
        JSONObject json= (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonParam).nextValue();
        jsonCartao = new cartao(json.get("NomeCartao").toString(), (double)json.get("SaldoRestante"), json.get("NomePessoa").toString(), (double)json.get("ValorUltimoCredito"), json.get("DataUltimoCredito").toString(), (boolean)json.get("Status"));
        return jsonCartao;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return jsonCartao;
    }
}
```

While debugging the code, the code jumps to `return jsonCartao;`, not to `e.printStackTrace();`:

[image: http://imgur.com/OhwmMw5]

Comment: You only enter the `catch` block if an error is thrown in the `try` block. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you add print the error and show it here? I highly doubt that `e == null`.

Comment: add e.printStacktrace() before return to see what is happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could use some improvements. Class names like `cartao` should start with UpperCase. You can return the object at the end of your function, no need to repeat code. Inside a `catch` you should analyze your error. You can also return the proper type instead of returning `Object` and casting to something else.

```
public Cartao parseJSON(String jsonParam){

    Cartao jsonCartao = new Cartao();

    try {
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(jsonParam).nextValue();
        jsonCartao = new Cartao(
            json.getString("NomeCartao"), 
            json.getDouble("SaldoRestante"), 
            json.getString("NomePessoa"),    
            json.getDouble("ValorUltimoCredito"), 
            json.getString("DataUltimoCredito"), 
            json.getBoolean("Status"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonCartao;
}
```

PS: During debugging, add breakpoints can help to relevant sections of the code

Answer (score 0):

Don't return the jsonCartao in the catch block, you should do something like

`System.out.println("Exception thrown  :" + e);`

That way you have something to analyse.